# How to define field names in Presto array_agg multiple columns

Tags: sql, presto

When I use
`array_agg((col_1, col_2, col_3))` in presto db, I get the output as

`[{field0=A, field1=112348.0, field2=22}, {field0=B, field1=10548.0, field2=2}, {field0=C, field1=19036.0, field2=4}]`

Instead of field0, field1 etc., I'd like to define my own names, so I get something like

`[{id=A, max_val=112348.0, num=22}, {id=B, max_val=10548.0, num=2}, {id=C, max_val=19036.0, num=4}]`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to cast the row using this formula. Not sure if there's a simpler way

```
    SELECT cast(
    ROW(42, true, 'abc') 
    as 
    ROW(A integer, B boolean, C varchar(3))
    );
```